# Simple redirecting Script issue

Tags: redirect, header

I tried to make a script where when a user types in the url and presses Go, it will go to that web page. I made it, but I noticed that it only worked with

```
http://
```

in front of it. So i used the strpos function to check whether

```
http://
```

is in the string and if it isn't it will add it to the url and go to the website. It works but now when a user types in the url **with** 'Http://' it will double it so it would be something like:

```
'http://http://www.example.com'.
```

How can I fix this?
This is the code:

```
<?

if ($_POST['submit']) {

$urlgo = $_POST['url'];

if (strpos($urlgo,'http://') == false) {

$url = "http://$urlgo";
header("Location: $url "); /* Redirect browser */

} else {

$urlgo = $_POST['url'];

header("Location: $urlgo "); /* Redirect browser */

exit;
} 

}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strpos($urlgo,'http://') == false) {
```

is the problem. `strpos` can return a LEGITIMATE `0` if the "needle" string (`http://`) is at the start of the "haystack" (`$urlgo`). `0 == false` is TRUE in PHP. You need to use the strict comparison operator:

```
if (strpos(...) === false) {
```

(note, **3** `=` signs) which compares type AND value. `0 === false` is FALSE in php.

Comment: How come the second part of the code did work though if == false indeed means "true" ? Because when you would type google.com it wouldn't work without the http:// .

Comment: `Location` redirects, by the http specs, are required to be a full URL. For convenience, browsers MAY choose to be lenient and see `Location: google.com` has a redirect to google. But by the strict spec, the redirect shouldn't work, or try to hit a file called `google.com` on the SAME site as the header call came from.